# npm run dev change server and url for nextjs/react frontend

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm setting up a flask backend and react/nextjs frontend for a webapp but I cannot get the the frontend start properly when running on a remote server.

When I run `npm run dev` on my local machine the response is:

`started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000`

But when I run the same command on a linux server the response is:

`started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000`

I would like to start the server on 0.0.0.0:3000 and have it accessible at that url as well. I've tried `npm run dev --hostname 0.0.0.0` and `HOST='0.0.0.0' npm run dev` but neither changed anything.

Server info:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.4 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.4"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.4 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.4:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.4
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.4"
```

Comment: you want to send requests to 0.0.0.0 from a client and have the server you deployed to respond?

Comment: Yes, if possible. My main issue is that when I check port 3000 in a browser after starting the server it does not load and says that the site can't be reached. This is only the case deploying from the remote linux server and not from my local machine.

I have not been able to find any other cases where npm run dev reported `started server on [::]:3000` either.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is an address a machine can use to refer to itself. If a network was asked "who has IP 0.0.0.0?" either everyone would respond, or nobody would. Either way it doesn't make sense. You need to use the IP of that machine, or set up DNS so you can use the name

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was confused since I had it working on my local machine and but couldn't get it started on the remote server. It turned out that port 3000 was closed on the server, after opening I was able to run it successfully with no other changes. Apologies for the misunderstanding.